# How to redirect to the canvas page after authentication?

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I am a noob and I need some help. I just created my first simple app and I ran into an problem. If a user opens this app for the first time and clicks on the 'allow' button on the authentication page, it jumps to the site where my app is stored and not to the canvas page where it should be displayed in iframe.

The app's url is https://apps.facebook.com/kpxyapp/

(I removed the appid and secret from the code below.)

I would be grateful if you could help. Thanks.

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '',
        'secret' => '',
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo "Hello my name is : {$me['name']}";
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        echo "<script>top.location.href=\"{$loginUrl}\"</script>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying this a lot too, finally found another post which directed me to http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development-php-sdk-3-0/. It really helped me solve the problem.

Good Luck !